# Is the derivative of delta function always equals to $0$?

Tags: analysis

By the definition that

$$\frac{d \delta}{d x}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d g_{n}}{d x}$$

where $g_{n}$ is a sequence of ordinary smooth functions which satisfy:

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} g_{n}(x)=0, \quad x \neq \xi$$

and

$$\int_{a}^{b} g_{n}(x) d x=1 \quad \text { for all } n$$

I found that $\displaystyle \frac{d \delta}{d x}$ always equals to $0$. Is that true?

---

Updated:

Thanks for the answer of @whpowell96 - that's also what I wanted to point. In general, it is clear that $\displaystyle \frac{d \delta}{d x}=\frac{d}{d x}(\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} g_{n}(x))$ due to the definition of the delta function. It seems that interchanging the order of derivatives and limits of smooth functions couldn't work! (And as @whpowell96 said, the definition by integration does work.)

But I found the definition like [$\displaystyle\frac{d \delta}{d x}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d g_{n}}{d x}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrl0P.png) (this is a picture!) from my textbook [Introduction to Partial Differential Equations on page 225](https://books.google.com/books?id=aQ8JAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=The%20graphs%20of%20these%20rational%20functions%20take%20the%20form%20of%20more%20and%20more%20concentrated%20spiked%20%E2%80%9Cdoublets%E2%80%9D,%20as%20illustrated%20in&source=bl&ots=urCo5hmArh&sig=ACfU3U2HZHReowdEhPI6Vk4jye-ZwAZpRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizl87wtPbgAhVEtIMKHcvPCY8Q6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%20graphs%20of%20these%20rational%20functions%20take%20the%20form%20of%20more%20and%20more%20concentrated%20spiked%20%E2%80%9Cdoublets%E2%80%9D%2C%20as%20illustrated%20in&f=false). I'm pretty confused about this definition. Did I misunderstand anything from this book?

Comment: In which space is the limit $\frac{d \delta}{d x}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d g_{n}}{d x}$ to be understood? Dirac delta is not a function in the traditional sense (but rather a distribution).

Comment: The derivative of $\delta$ is not zero. Instead, $\delta^\prime$ is the distribution which maps $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $-\varphi^\prime(0)$.

Comment: @rolandcyp Thanks for your answer! I do need the exact answer (that the derivative of $delta$ is not zero). But please give just one moment to update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be very careful when interchanging the order of derivatives and limits of smooth functions because $g_n$ converges to $\delta$, which is certainly not a smooth function. Even if the limit you describe does converge to 0, it is unlikely to be useful because you are interchanging operations which require pretty strict requirements to justify doing so. You can define the derivative of a non-smooth function like this:

For a "function" (distribution) $f$, we define $f'$ to be the "function" (distribution) such that
$$\int_Uf'\phi dx = -\int_Uf\phi'dx$$
for all smooth functions $\phi$ defined on $U$. Now recall that $\int_U \delta(x-y)\phi(x)dx=\phi(y)$ as a definition. Using this, you can pretty easily verify that $\delta'$ satisfies $\int_U \delta'(x-y) \phi(x)dx = -\phi'(y)$ for any smooth function $\phi$ defined on $U$. So you can take this to be the definition of $\delta'$ and ignore all the nasty limits

Comment: I totally agree with you but please give me one moment to add some other details for the question.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. Would you please help me?